# Reanimated Mismatch between JavaScript part and native part of Reanimated 3.0.0-rc.9 vs. undefined

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, rctbridge

I am trying to show a react native screen from my native(swift code) UIViewController using RCTRootView. I keep getting this mismatch error that I think is related to expo, I have tried re-registering the component in various ways, as well as setting jsCodeLocation straight to local host with no avail

Error Message.

[image: error message]

Index.js.
[image: index.js]

babel-config js
[image: babel-config js]

ViewController
[image: ViewController]

Comment: Are you using a monorepo? Do you see the error in development, production, or both?

Comment: yes it is a mono repo and  I only tested the project in Development @Slbox

Comment: nope question still stands @Max

Comment: If you're using expo, you may need to downgrade `react-native-reanimated` to the same version that is bundled with the expo SDK. e.g. 2.14.4

Comment: done that. downgraded and upgraded to different versions. didn't work

Comment: Did you sort this out ?

Comment: no I didn't  @Googlian

Comment: Try to run npm i react-native-reanimated

Answer (score 2):

npx expo install react-native-reanimated

Then inside your bable.config.js
paste        plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/